# react native error unrecognized operator min

Tags: react-native

There is an error of `unrecognized operator min`

[image: screenshot]

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into the same thing.  I was also getting warnings from expo for:

- react-native-gesture-handler - expected version range: ~1.6.0 - actual version installed: ^1.7.0
- react-native-reanimated - expected version range: ~1.9.0 - actual version installed: ^1.10.1
- react-native-safe-area-context - expected version range: ~3.0.7 - actual version installed: ^3.1.1

I reinstalled those with expo and the problem went away.

expo install... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Run expo update @38.0.0
or your expo update @<your_sdk_version>
If it shows an error then delete your yarn-lock file and it should work fine!!

Answer (score 0):

i think your IDE exidently
add this line in
import { min } from "react-native-reanimated";

just remove this and your error fixed