# Unrecognised Operator min react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

I have this error when running application, look at my versions:

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.3",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.7",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.2",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.8.0",
"expo": "~38.0.8",
"expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
"react": "~16.11.0",
"react-dom": "~16.11.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.10.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.11.7"

expo-cli 3.22.3
```

Help

Comment: Does this solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63038614/why-react-native-error-unrecognized-operator-min?

Comment: Can you add the error page so that It will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved, remove react-native-safe-area-context in version ^3.1.1 and change it to 0.7.3

Also sdk 38 change to 37

Answer (score 0):

I just solved, remove react-native-safe-area-context in version ^3.1.1 and change it to 0.7.3

Also sdk 38 change to 37
"@react-native-community/masked-view": ^0.1.10 chenge to 0.1.6,
"react-native-gesture-handler": ^1.7.0 chenge to ~1.6.0,
"react-native-reanimated": ^1.10.1 chenge to ~1.7.0,

Expo in my smartphone version: 2.16.1